# WCF Service method is failing since UK Daylight Savings Time ended on Sunday

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, datetime

I have a number of Windows Mobile PDAs that are all communicating with a central server. Since Sunday, every PDA has failed to update. The method it's failing on is the first step of my sync service which calls:

```
ServerTimeContract timeContract = Service.GetServerDateTime();
```

The code on the WCF side is:

```
public ServerTimeContract GetServerDateTime()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    return new ServerTimeContract(now.ToUniversalTime(), 
        now.IsDaylightSavingTime());
}
```

For completeness, this is the `ServerTimeContract`:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class ServerTimeContract
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; private set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool IsDaylightSavings { get; private set; }

    public ServerTimeContract(DateTime dateTime, bool isDaylightSavings)
    {
        DateTime = dateTime;
        IsDaylightSavings = isDaylightSavings;
    }
}
```

If I change the date to the 27/10/2012 on my PC and run the above code, then it works fine. If I change the Date back to today's today, I get an exception saying "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly".

The PDAs throw the error "Unable to read data from the transport connection".

What's even more bizarre, is if I change the return method to always pass `true` in the second constructor argument, everything works:

```
public ServerTimeContract GetServerDateTime()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    return new ServerTimeContract(now.ToUniversalTime(), true);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't daylight savings time end on Nov 4?  Not that I can see how that would directly matter, but...

Comment: GMT+00. I'm in the UK. Our daylights saving ended on the 28/10/2012.

Comment: What are your security settings? Perhaps this is a problem with something like the [MaxClockSkew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738468.aspx)?

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with the time directly. That true/false value for IsDaylightSavings doesn't even get used by the PDAs. If I remove that boolean value, it all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I just removed the `IsRequired = true` from the IsDaylightSavings property on my contract. If anyone wants to comment and explain why, that'd be good. Although I'm pretty certain the attribute was unnecessary in this instance anyway.